# About Main Menu in joomla

Tags: joomla1.5

In admin , main menu is not displaying from menu manager but other menus like footer menu and header menu are displaying / working.

Answer (score 0):

Has it been created?  Was it accidentally deleted?
You may be able to recreate it - or go into the module manager and make sure that there's the appropriate module for it!

Comment: Hi Hanny...

Suddenly the menu items in my admin section has dissapeared. I can add new menu items in admin but not visible in the admin panel . What is wrong?


I also Check it the value of Published and it is set to 1 so that is not the problem.

Everything within jos_modules is said to 1 in published.
I m quite sure i did not do anything to make it disappear. :(

Comment: So when you login as an administrator (make sure you're logged in as Super Admin) and you go to 'menu manager' you don't see any of those menus?  Is that correct?